# Can you play Roblox on Ubuntu 23.10?

Tags: system-installation, games

Can we play Roblox on the new version of Ubuntu 23.10?

Comment: I was looking for this myself and found this https://roblox.fandom.com/wiki/Tutorial:Using_Roblox_on_Linux  Looks like the Roblox developers are deliberately blocking the use of the kind of Linux applications that enable this kind of thing

Comment: please don't ask question that have a yes or no as an answer. find install instructions and see how far you get. if that leads to an error you can't fix yourself ask about it.

Comment: The only possible duplicate for this question has a link-only answer, and the link has a banner that says that the instructions on the website are obsolete.